# How can i get user id from nextjs session

Tags: next.js, next-auth

How can i Get the user id from getServerSession(authoptions)

the session only have email,name and image
**Here is the authoptions**

```html
const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  pages: {
    signIn: '/auth/login',
  },
  providers: [
   
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: 'Email',
          type: 'email',
          placeholder: 'Email',
        },
        password: {
          label: 'Password',
          type: 'password',
          placeholder: 'Password',
        },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const parsedCredentials = z
          .object({ email: z.string().email(), password: z.string().min(4) })
          .safeParse(credentials);
        if (parsedCredentials.success) {
         

          const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
            where: { email: credentials.email },
          });

          if (!user) return null;

          const passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(credentials.password, user.hashedPassword!);

          return passwordsMatch ? user : null;
        }
        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],

  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
};

export default authOptions;
```

```html
const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  if (!session) return NextResponse.json({}, { status: 401 });

  console.log(session.user);
```

this only has email,name, and image but I want to have id also
I’m using
“next”: “^14.0.4”,
“next-auth”: “^4.24.5”

Answer (score -1):

The `getServerSession` function retrieves the session information, but as you've noticed, it only includes the email, name, and image by default. If you want to include additional information in the session, such as the user's ID, you need to customize the `session` callback in your NextAuth configuration.

Here's how you can modify the `session` callback to include the user's ID:

1. Update the `authOptions` configuration to include a `callbacks` object.
2. Within the `callbacks` object, define a `session` callback.
3. Inside the `session` callback, you can add additional properties to the session object. Here, you can add the user's ID.

Here is an example of how you can modify your `authOptions`:

```js
const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  // ... your existing configuration

  callbacks: {
    session: async ({ session, user }) => {
      // Add the user ID to the session object
      session.user.id = user.id;
      return session;
    },
  },

  // ... the rest of your configuration
};
```

In this example, the `session` callback receives the current session object and the user object. The user object should contain the user's ID (assuming it's present in the user model in your database). You then assign the user's ID to the `session.user.id` property.

After making this change, when you retrieve the session using `getServerSession`, it should now include the user's ID along with the email, name, and image.

Ensure that the user model in your database actually includes an `id` field and that this field is returned by the `authorize` function. This way, the `id` will be available in the user object inside the `session` callback.

https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks

```
import prisma from "@/lib/PrismaClient";
import { compare } from "bcryptjs";
import type { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

const AuthOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 180,
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "UtransVox",
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: "Email",
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "example@example.com",
          required: true,
        },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password", required: true },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        if (!credentials?.email || !credentials.password) {
          return null;
        }

        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: {
            email: credentials.email,
          },
          include: {
            profile: true,
          },
        });
        if (user?.role !== "ADMIN") {
          return null;
        }
        if (!user?.password) {
          return null;
        }
        if (!user || !(await compare(credentials.password, user.password))) {
          return null;
        }

        return {
          id: user.id.toString(),
          email: user.email,
          name: user.profile?.nickname,
          role: user.role,
          randomKey: user.randomKey,
        };
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    jwt: async ({ token, user, account, profile }) => {
      if (user) {
        const u = user as unknown as any;

        return {
          ...token,
          id: u.id,
          role: u.role,
          randomKey: u.randomKey,
        };
      }
      return token;
    },
    session: async ({ session, token, user, newSession, trigger }) => {
      const admin = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: {
          id: Number(token.id),
        },
      });
      const res = {
        ...session,
        user: {
          ...session.user,
          id: token.id,
          role: token.role,
          randomKey: token.randomKey,
        },
      };
      if (admin?.randomKey !== token.randomKey) {
        return {
          ...res,
          error: "Session expired",
        };
      }
      return res;
    },
  },
};

export default AuthOptions;
```

This is my example, you can research.

Comment: 'Get the following errors
session.user' is possibly 'undefined' 
Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ name?: string | null | undefined; email?: string | null | undefined; image?: string | null | undefined; }'

Comment: I'll give you my example.